# Why is 12313123213456789 == 12313123213456788 true?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Can someone ELI5 why is this the case?

```
console.log(12313123213456789 === 12313123213456788);
=> true
```

Comment: Check `console.log( Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER )`

Comment: Only integers up to 2^53 can be *distinctly* represented - a double is used for all numeric values. This is a duplicate, I am sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350175/max-integer-value-in-javascript

Comment: I just answered a question like this yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190594/why-are-2-different-numbers-equal-in-javascript/25190668#25190668

Answer (score 0):

[numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

All numbers in JS are 64 bit floating point numbers. the largest integral value is 2 pow 53, or 9007199254740992.